# Почему у меня возникает ошибка при создании простого цикла из 100 итераций?

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
try {
 var str = 'e';
 for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  str += str;
 }
 console.log('попытка');
} catch(e) {
 console.log('ошибка');
}
// Оставшаяся синхронно выполняемая часть кода.
console.log('остаток');
```

```js
'use strict';
try {
 var str = 'e';
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  str += str;
 }
 console.log('попытка');
} catch(e) {
 console.log('ошибка');
}
// Оставшаяся синхронно выполняемая часть кода.
console.log('остаток');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что Вы пытаетесь создать строку длиной два в сотой степени букв 'e'.

Это примерно 10 в тридцатой степени символов. Попробуйте посчитать, сколько это будет в гигабайтах.

```js
'use strict';
try {
  var str = 'e';
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    str += str;
  }
  console.log('попытка');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('ошибка');
}
// Оставшаяся синхронно выполняемая часть кода.
console.log('остаток');
console.log(str.length);
```

```js
'use strict';
try {
  var str = 'e';
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    str += str;
  }
  console.log('попытка');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('ошибка');
}
// Оставшаяся синхронно выполняемая часть кода.
console.log('остаток');
console.log(str.length, str);
```

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff Вы невнимательно прочитали мой ответ. Попробуйте еще раз. Постарайтесь не хамить.

Comment: Я не понимаю что происходит. Вы можете нормально ответить???

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понимаю. Я просто 100 раз делаю конкатенацию строки 'e'. Какая степень? Это же просто строка. Я сейчас поэкспериментировал со строкой из другой буквы (если вы имели ввиду exponential notation). Что происходит? Я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: Это ограничение в js. If the size of the resulting string would exceed an
implementation-specific limit, this method will throw an Error. This limit is
equal to `2^28 - 16` in V8.

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff Ваш код на каждой итерации увеличивает строку в два раза. Вы хотели написать `str += 'e';`?

Comment: e + e, ee + ee, eeee + eeee, eeee eeee + eeee eeee ... Это только первые 4 шага итерации.

Comment: Да. Да. Вы правы. Я понял. Я не понимал в чём ошибка. Да, я хотел просто присоединять 'e'. Спасибо.

Comment: @Igor А за что мне минусы ставят???

Comment: @ValeraRybakoff Пожалуйста. Успехов! Насчет минусов - не расстривайтесь, это демократия в действии :). Мне тоже ставят.